# How to merge this `IF ... ELSE`in a Stored-Procedure?

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, stored-procedures

i have a feeling that this SP could be simplified.
Is it possible to eliminate that `IF...ELSE` and merge it with the same `WHERE`-Condition?

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[UpdateRmaModelWithTacList](
    @onlyNoModel bit 
)
AS
IF @onlyNoModel=1 
BEGIN
    UPDATE  RMA
    SET       ModelID = COALESCE(modModel.idModel, 1)
    FROM      tabTAC INNER JOIN
                modModel ON tabTAC.fiModel = modModel.idModel RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                 RMA ON tabTAC.TAC = SUBSTRING(RMA.IMEI, 1, 8)
    WHERE     (RMA.ModelID = 1)
END 
ELSE
BEGIN
    UPDATE RMA
    SET      ModelID = COALESCE(modModel.idModel, RMA.ModelID)
    FROM     tabTAC INNER JOIN
              modModel ON tabTAC.fiModel = modModel.idModel RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                RMA ON tabTAC.TAC = SUBSTRING(RMA.IMEI, 1, 8)
END

RETURN @@ROWCOUNT;

Go
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WHERE (@onlyNoModel != 1 OR RMA.ModelID = 1)
```

Whether this is as efficient as the `IF..ELSE` version is up to the query optimizer. The `WHERE` will hopefully be optimized away by any decent optimizer if `@onlyNoModel` is not 1.

Comment: Thank you, that easy, sometimes i'm thinking too complicated. Performance is not a key factor for this SP.